# IEVRPresenterRegisterCallback in MVVM gives D3DERR_DRIVERINVALIDCALL

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working with the enhanced video renderer in WPF and when creating an instance of IEVRPresenterRegisterCallback I sometimes get an annoying error of D3DERR_DRIVERINVALIDCALL.

Using the MVVM design, when I switch views... one view specifically has this presenter inside of it... and runs about 80% of the time when switching between views. When a view is closed, everything is disposed... so going back to the same view will recreate the objects.

The problem is sometimes it does work... and I've nailed down the cause, but can't figure out a solution.

```
        int hr;
        object comObject;
        Exception exception = null;

        // A COM object we query form our native library.
        IClassFactory factory = null;

        // Create our 'helper' class.
        var evrPresenter = new EVRPresenter();

        // Call the DLL export to create the class factory.
        if (ProcessBits == 64)
        {
            hr = DllGetClassObject64(EVR_PRESENTER_CLSID, IUNKNOWN_GUID, out comObject);
        }
        else
        {
            exception = new Exception(string.Format("{0} bit processes are unsupported", ProcessBits));
            goto bottom;
        }

        // Check if our call to our DLL failed.
        if (hr != 0 || comObject == null)
        {
            exception = new COMException("Could not create a new class factory.", hr);
            goto bottom;
        }

        // Cast the COM object that was returned to a COM interface type.
        factory = comObject as IClassFactory;

        if (factory == null)
        {
            exception = new Exception("Could not QueryInterface for the IClassFactory interface.");
            goto bottom;
        }

        // Get the GUID of the IMFVideoPresenter.
        Guid guidVideoPresenter = typeof(IMFVideoPresenter).GUID;

        // Creates a new instance of the IMFVideoPresenter.
        hr = factory.CreateInstance(null, ref guidVideoPresenter, out comObject);

        // QueryInterface for the IMFVideoPresenter.
        var presenter = comObject as IMFVideoPresenter;

        // QueryInterface for our callback registration interface.
        var registerCb = comObject as IEVRPresenterRegisterCallback;

        if (registerCb == null)
        {
            exception = new Exception("Could not QueryInterface for IEVRPresenterRegisterCallback.");
            goto bottom;
        }

        // Register the callback to the 'helper' class.
        registerCb.RegisterCallback(evrPresenter);

        // Populate the IMFVideoPresenter.
        evrPresenter.VideoPresenter = presenter;

    bottom:
        if (factory != null)
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(factory);
        }

        if (exception != null)
        {
            throw exception;
        }

        return evrPresenter;
```

When facotry.CreateInstance(null, ref guidVideoPresenter, out comObject) runs... the comObject returns IEVRPresenterRegisterCallback most of the time, however other times, it spits out null and the HRESULT is D3DERR_DRIVERINVALIDCALL which so happens to be a very vague error code.

When this happens my application eventually catches the exception and continues without showing any video.

Has anybody seen something like this before in this type of design?

Cheers.

Comment: By adding a 'goto top' statement if comObject is null eventually rectifies the issue... this be said... it continues to loop until comObject is not null and CreateInstance finally works... but theres no telling how long it takes for it to finally work.

Comment: However this in turn caused 6GB of memory to be used until finally rendererd... and thats with the loop alone.